# issue autolload_file when i execute index.php inside phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have problem with load index.php. When i start localhost/phpmyadmin everything is correct untill i will run index.php. I get error about File ' . AUTOLOAD_FILE . ' missing or not readable. Below is img how it looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sPzY.jpg

I installed composer and it nothing changed. Tried do all steps from link "Most likely you did not run Composer to ' . '' . 'install library files " and nothing works. I installed newest version php moved to share folder and the result was the same.

Comment: Do you have a webserver installed?

Comment: Yes i have apache

Comment: Is it configured to run PHP code

Comment: I configured httpd.conf after install phpmyadmin https://imgur.com/a/ZI28EEV

Comment: I am not sure you got it right. Can you put a simple file in the DocumentRoot (htdocs) like this `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` call it `fred.php` and then try running `locahost/fred.php`

Comment: Let us know what happens

Comment: i have got forbidden about permission to access to this resource

Comment: What OS are you using

Comment: I am using macos/unix os